# Android : TabActivity or Fragment? When to use Tabs, when Fragments?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabs, tabactivity

I want to create an application which one of its pages must like below :

[image: tabs]

Each tab contains some `View`s ( like a form )

After some search, I know there is two ways for implementing above layout. `TabActivity` and `Fragment`. But I have not use neither Tab nor Fragment in my projects(cause i have short experience on Android)

Now which of these ways I should use? Clearly, I want to know which is more suitable to use? (According to the better one, if there is a brief and clear tutorial, please introduce it to me)

**Note** : In this case, the application must run on Android 2.3.3+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TabActivity` is deprecated. You shouldn't use it, especially if it's an entirely new project.

Fragments are available for older SDKs via the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html), so you can use them in 2.3.3+ with no problems.

Comment: Thanks for your response @matiash. So useful answer...
If you have any link for Fragment tutorial, please share it with me. Thanks again :)

Comment: There are many. I would suggest starting with the official one from Android Training: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Comment: OK... Good luck bro ;)